# Inheriting setter, overwriting getter in python abstract class

Tags: python, inheritance, properties, abc

Say you have an attribute in a base class with a single `setter` method that will be used in all subclasses, but with different `getter` methods in all subclasses.  Ideally you only want to write the code for the `setter` method once in the base class.  Additionally, you want to make the base class abstract because it doesn't have a complete `getter` method.  Is there any way to do this?

Naively, I think it should go something like this:

```
class _mystring(object):

    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractproperty
    def str(self):
        pass

    @str.setter
    def str(self,value):
        self._str = value

class uppercase(_mystring):

    @_mystring.str.getter
    def str(self):
        return self._str.upper()
```

But `upper = uppercase()` fails with `Can't instantiate abstract class uppercase with abstract methods str`.

If I change the `@abc.abstractproperty` in class `_mystring` to `@property`, then `upper = uppercase()` works, but so does `upper = _mystring()`, which I don't want.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make a small wrapper around `abstractproperty` that will do it:

```
class partialAP(abc.abstractproperty):
    def getter(self, func):
        if getattr(func, '__isabstractmethod__', False) or getattr(self.fset, '__isabstractmethod__', False):
            p = partialAP(func, self.fset)
        else:
            p = property(func, self.fset)
        return p

    def setter(self, func):
        if getattr(self.fget, '__isabstractmethod__', False) or getattr(func, '__isabstractmethod__', False):
            p = partialAP(self.fget, func)
        else:
            p = property(self.fset, func)
        return p
```

Then your code works with just a slight modification:

```
class _mystring(object):

    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @partialAP
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def str(self):
        pass

    @str.setter
    def str(self,value):
        self._str = value

class uppercase(_mystring):

    @_mystring.str.getter
    def str(self):
        return self._str.upper()
```

And then the behavior is as desired:

```
>>> _mystring()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    _mystring()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class _mystring with abstract methods str
>>> u = uppercase()
>>> u.str = 'a'
>>> u.str
'A'
```

My `partialAP` wrapper must be used in conjuction with `abc.abstractmethod`.  What you do is you use `abstractmethod` to decorate the "piece" of the property (getter or setter) that you want to be abstract, and use `partialAP` as a second decorator.  `partialAP` defines getter/setter functions that replace the property with a normal one only if both getter and setter are non-abstract.

Obviously you'd have to extend this a bit to make it worth with property deleters too.  There could also be corner cases that won't be handled right if you have a more complex inheritance hierarchy.

Old solution for posterity:

```
class _mystring(object):

    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _strGet(self):
        pass

    def _strSet(self,value):
        self._str = value

    str = property(_strGet, _strSet)

class uppercase(_mystring):

    def _strGet(self):
        return self._str.upper()
    str = _mystring.str.getter(_strGet)
```

Then it works:

```
>>> _mystring()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
    _mystring()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class _mystring with abstract methods _strGet
>>> u = uppercase()
>>> u.str = 'a'
>>> u.str
'A'
```

The trick is that you have to not use the convenient decorators.  The `abstractproperty` decorator marks the entire property as abstract.  What you have to do is create two methods, an abstract one (for the getter) and a regular one (for the setter), then create a regular property that combines them.  Then when you extend the class, you must override the abstract getter and explicitly "mix" it with the base class property (using `_mystring.str.getter`).

The reason you can't use `@_mystring.str.getter` is that the decorator forces both the getter and the setter to have the same name as the property itself.  If you want to mark just one of the two as abstract, they have to have different names or you can't get at them separately.

Note that this solution requires subclasses to give their getters the right name (`_strGet` in this case), in order to satisfy the ABC that they have overriden the abstract method.

Comment: This is a bummer, since using the decorators is much more pythonic.  The only thing the abstract class hides from the base class in this case is the name of the setter function, since you have to know the right getter name and have to do the explicit mixing.

Comment: @Seanslice: See my edited answer.  I was able to cook up a modified version of `abstractproperty` that allows you to mark the getter/setter as abstract independently and use the decorators.